# Should we have a non-reputable source for a delete vote?

Tags: discussion

So every so often I see an answer from a bad source, like greekmythology.com or Rick Riordan.

So there are answers with no sources, which are still answers, I guess, but what about completely wrong sources?

Should we downvote and move on? Edit? Or flag?

Comment: Based on a recent answer by MalayTheDynamo, it appears Riordan has written a fairly faithful adaptation of some foundational Greek Myths in Percy Jackson's Greek Gods , which could be viewed as a suitable reference work for young adults. (I haven't read it, but I'm adding it to my list so I can see what Riordan says.)

I've never heard anyone praise Riordan for being a fine classical scholar (compare to say, Robert Graves,) but he certainly has a lot of young eyes on his work, and we should probably consider young adults interested in mythology as a growth demographic for Stack Mythology.

Comment: Surely the whole point of the SE system is that posts with the sources that the community regards as the best - get the most votes.  The system works just as it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please do not flag, moderators are not arbiters of correctness.

If you do happen to have better sources that back up whatever the answer is saying, then, by all means, add them to the answer. Either by editing them in or by suggesting them in comments. Do not just remove what you consider bad sources, though.

If you do not happen to have better sources, but have the time and energy to politely explain why the answer's sources aren't ideal, then comment.

Otherwise, downvote and move on.